# Change layout width if image doesn't fit

Tags: android

I have a viewpager which is showing pics from a sd card. Everything works fine if the picture which is showing has a good resolution and fits the entire screen, but the problem appears when my pic has a layout height of half of the screen, or a layout width of half of the screen. What can I do to fix this problem?

here is my Viewpager adapter:

```
public class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

private List<ImageView> images;

public ImagePagerAdapter(List<ImageView> images) {
    this.images = images;
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    ImageView imageView = images.get(position);
    container.addView(imageView);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_START);
    return imageView;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    container.removeView(images.get(position));
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return images.size();
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object o) {
    return view == o;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP` or `ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE`. You can read more on [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html).